# How can timeout be implemented given the blocking nature of recvfrom and sendto?

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to achieve the `TIMEOUT` functionality in my UDP Stop-and-wait. That is, I make my receiver not send `ACK` on purpose and expect the sender re-transmit after the `TIMEOUT`.

However, as the the [recvfrom](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) documentation says:

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking.

So both my sender and receiver get stuck at `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`. They both hang! THere most be a way so that I can make the code keep running so as to achieve the `TIMEOUT`.

How may I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option via the `setsockopt()` function. Then if the timeout triggers, `recvfrom()` will return -1 with `errno` set to either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: This is how I chose to do it in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the functions `select` `poll` and `epoll`. They can help with the timeout. They are also very useful when waiting on mulitple file descriptors (sockets)